# SVG <use> element not inheriting event handlers in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, svg

EDIT: This is a bug in Firefox, and cannot be resolved without editing Firefox directly, which I have no desire to do. I consider this question resolved for the purpose of asking other people for he.

I am trying to create a pixel-based drawing program using SVG. I initialize the event handlers on a couple of `<polygon>`s inside a `<defs>`, and then copy that a bunch of times with `<use>`s to make the the canvas, and it works fine, in Chrome.

But regardless of whether I assign the `.onclick` attribute or use `.addEventListener`, my `<use>`s don't register anything in Firefox. As I was researching solutions for this, I found another thematically, and possibly technically, related phenomenon: `<use>`s copied using `.cloneNode` also do not retain event listeners. I *could* assign each `<use>` element the event listeners as I generate them, but it seems to me that that is the least desirable solution.

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's [bug 265895](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=265895) or [bug 575470 ](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=575470). Your only option is to download the source code of Firefox and fix the bug or pay someone else to do so.

Comment: @RobertLongson I was afraid of that. I guess I'll just use the suboptimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I came up with is to register the same event listener on the use element. After that it works in Firefox, but not anymore in IE, Safari and Chrome, because the event gets fired twice. Therefore you have to de-register the event of the copied SVG element. It is a workaround, but no good solution. I hope someone else can give a better answer for that.